# Getting error as below in using Gradle in Grobid

Tags: java, gradle, grobid

I am trying to install Grobid in Ubuntu 64 bit.

Referred from

```
https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Install-Grobid/  


$/GROBID_LATEST_0.5.1/grobid-0.5.1$ ./gradlew clean install 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':grobid-core:compileJava' >property 'classpath' during up-to-date check.
> Error snapshotting jar [wipo-analysers-0.0.2.jar]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
$/GROBID_LATEST_0.5.1/grobid-0.5.1$
```

Kindly help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Run the command with _--stacktrace_ and see the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps to solve your problem.

```
$java -version
```

Remove latest version of java(i.e. 10 or 11) because gradle is not compatible with java 10 and 11.Instal java 7/8/9.

```
$sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*

Then

$ sudo apt-get update

$apt-cache search openjdk
$sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk
$cd grobid

$./gradlew run
```